# How to execute linux commands in the shell opened through /bin/bash

Tags: linux, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am new to Linux stuff and would like to know how to run command while opening the shell through `/bin/bash`?

Eg the steps that I want to perform:

**Step1:** Run the docker exec command to start the quickstart virtual machine.

```
$ docker exec -it 7f8c1a16e5b2 /bin/bash
```

**Step2:** The above command gives the handle of the quickstart vm on the console. Now I want to run the below command by default when ever some one starts the docker quickstart console (step 1)

```
cd
. ./.bash_profile
```

I need some guidance on how to do this. Obviously, putting all these statements in one shell script isn't helping as the commands of *Step2* are to be executed in the newly opened shell (of quickstart vm). The idea is to put all these statements in a single shell script and execute it when we want to get hold of the session within the VM console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the commands you want to be executed inside the container to bash with the `-c` option.

That would look something like this:

```sh
docker exec -it 7f8c1a16e5b2 /bin/bash -c "cd && . ./.bash_profile && /bin/bash"
```

Comment: I tried the below statement to go to the home directory (as an example). But after executing it, I didn't even get the VM console. docker exec -it 7f8c1a16e5b2 /bin/bash -c "cd"

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot if you want an interactive shell you need to add a `&& /bin/bash` at the end.